# doing a filter by search bar in javascript, within laravel blade/HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, laravel

I have a laravel blade template that drives our current site, which shows furniture groups, each containing several items/pieces of furniture. This page is built using `foreach` loops in laravel, both for the furniture groups, built by `$orderformdata->pgroups` and the pieces in the groups, built by `$pgroup->pskus`.

I have a search bar, with no submit button, that was once driven by angular and used to do a live filter on the page. I.e., if you entered 'sofa' anything not containing the word sofa would immediately disappear from the page. So I'm not looking for autocomplete, rather a live search bar filter without a submit button or function.

I'm not a pro with javascript and I don't know how to do this. I have a JSON encode variable for these products, but I was also thinking I could use JS or JQuery to filter by my foreach loops.

Here's the Javascript for the page, including the JSON object, and the search JS which is currently not working:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var orderFormData = <?php echo json_encode ($tempdata);?>;
</script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("srch-term");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
    if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
   } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
   }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

And here's the blade with the search bar and main group foreach loops:

```
<div class="uk-width-5-10">

        <div class="md-input-wrapper search-form">
            <form id="searchProducts">
                <input type="text" class="md-input label-fixed" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" autofocus placeholder="Search Products"/>
                <span class="md-input-bar"></span>

            </form>
        </div>

<?php
$tempdata = [];
$i = 0;
?>

@foreach ($orderFormData->pgroups as $pgroup)
        <h3 style="font-size: 26px; padding: 10px 0;">{{ $pgroup->group_name }} - {{ $pgroup->group_code }}</h3>
        <p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" >{!! html_entity_decode($pgroup->group_desc) !!}</p> <!--Group Description-->



            <div class="uk-width-8-10">
                <table class="uk-table" style="width: 100%; min-width: 768px;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10%; font-size: 20px;">Frame</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%; font-size: 20px;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px;">Cover/Color</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px;">Cover/Color</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%; font-size: 20px;">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="width: 15%; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;"><b>Price</b></th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    @foreach ($pgroup->pskus as $psku)
                    <?php $tempdata['sku-' . $i] = $psku ?>
                    <tr class="@if (isset($psku->quantity) && $psku->quantity > 0) {{ highlight }} @endif">
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->frame_fmt }}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{!! html_entity_decode($psku->frame_desc) !!}</td>
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->cover1_code }}/{{ $psku->color1_code }} {{ $psku->color1_desc }}</td> 
                        <td style="font-weight: 500; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">{{ $psku->cover2_code }}/{{ $psku->color2_code }} {{ $psku->color2_desc }}</td>

                        <td style="font-weight: 700; line-height: 30px; font-size: 14px;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; display: block; width: 100%;">${{ $psku->price }}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @if ($psku->avail_date)
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: 700;">Available Date:</td>
                        <td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('dmY', $psku->avail_date)->toDateString() }}

                    </tr>
                    @endif
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
@endforeach
```

I think my current JS is going the wrong route anyway, but I need some help getting started with an appropriate JS method. I can play with how it filters things from there, but this at least gives an idea of my structure.

ANy tips on how I can apply a good JS live filter to this search bar/page would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

More easy to do with front-end framework.

I'm not sure if it is the best method but i would try that:

```
var searchBar = document.getElementById("srch-term");
var tbody = document.querySelectorAll('tbody');
searchBar.addEventListener("change", filterOnChange);

function filterOnChange(e) {
  var text = e.target.text;
  tbody.innerHTML = ''; //remove old data form the view
  var viewData = orderFormData.pgroup.filter(order => order.title === text) // i don't know exacly the structure of your json, your should adapt this line, your json is more nested.
  var tds;
   viewData.forEach(order => { 
                        var element = document.createElement(td)
                        td.innerTextElement = order.name;
                        tds.push(td);  
                    })
  tbody.appendChild(tds)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dataTables.js plugin of jQuery which is very convenient and easy to use and have a builtin searchbar in which you can search anything and the table would be shrink according to your searching criteria. you can sort your table in ascending and decending order which is also builtin. 
here is the links of cdn.

**CSS:**
    //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

**JS:**
    //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

**jQuery:**
    `$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });`

just give this id to your table:
`#myTable`